# How do I configure Azure Load Balancer to forward traffic to an external endpoint?

Tags: azure, load-balancing, azure-networking

I have a few of the same public endpoints exposed which I'd like my load balancer to route traffic to, but I can't figure out how to specify a backend pool that consists of these external endpoints - it seems I can only specify Azure resources.

So short of creating VM's as reverse proxies, how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Azure Application gateway for that. You can use Azure Load Balancer for this type of task.